# list of string to int conversion

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to convert a `list` of python elements from `str` to `int`.

My initial list looks like this:

```
l1 = ['723', '124', '1,211', '356']
```

The code I tried:

```
l1 =  list(map(int, l1))
```

Resulted in an error that tells me:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,211'
```

Alternatively, I tried `map`ing with `float`:

```
l1 =  list(map(float, l1))
```

but, this also resulted in an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,211'
```

I have tried both `int` and `float` in the code using map function. Can anyone correct me on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Is `1,211` supposed to be "1 point 211" or "1 thousand 211"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with a simple list comprehension.

```
>>> l1 = ['723', '124', '1,211', '356']
>>> [int(i.replace(',','')) for i in l1]
[723, 124, 1211, 356]
```

Answer (score 4):

Mapping either `int` or `float` to a value containing `','` will fail as converting `str`s to floats or ints has the requirement that they represent correctly formed numbers (Python doesn't allow `','` as separators for floats *or* for thousands, it conflicts with tuples)

If `','` is a thousands separator, use `replace(',', '')` (as @tobias_k noted) in the comprehension you supply to `map` and apply the `int` immediately:

```
r = list(map(int , (i.replace(',', '') for i in l1)))
```

to get a wanted result for `r` of:

```
[723, 124, 1211, 356]
```

Comment: it is 1211 and not 1.211. What should I do in this case?

Comment: In this case, `i.replace(',', '')`

Comment: Nice solutions, but I don't understand why you need to form the list of floats and then list of int. Why don't you form a list of int directly?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque my initial approach was based on a confusion of OPs requirements. The float needs to be mapped first because `int` cannot transform a `str` in the form of a float.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
l1 = ['723', '124', '1,211', '356']
l1 = [int(i.replace(',','')) for i in l1]
for x in l1:
    print("{:,}".format(x))
```

Output:

```
723
124
1,211
356
```